# How do I return a variable from nested For Loops in JavaScript without using a global variable?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope, return

Here is my code sans input

```js
// Check if three addends equal sum and return the product if so
let result;
function addNumbers(first,second,third,sum) {
    if (first + second + third === sum) {
        result = first * second * third;
        return (first * second * third);
    }
};

// find three numbers in list that add up to specific number
function testResult(list,sum) {
    let firstAddend;
    let secondAddend;
    let thirdAddend;
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        firstAddend = list.shift();
        for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            secondAddend = list[j];
            for (let k = 1; k < list.length; k++) {
                thirdAddend = list[k];
                addNumbers(firstAddend,secondAddend,thirdAddend,sum);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What I want is `testResult()` to return the result from `addNumbers()` when it returns the product. I want to get rid of `let result;` and `result = ...` in `addNumbers()`. I've been confused about scope but I think I'm starting to understand. Does each `for` loop contain the scope of the previous? If anyone is interested this is from Advent of Code Day 1. I am not certain if having the data is necessary here. If it is let me know and I will edit accordingly.

Comment: It's unclear where you are using `result`. Also, you say you want `testResult` to return something, but it has no `return` statement? I suspect you're looking for something like `const result = addNumbers(firstAddend,secondAddend,thirdAddend,sum);`, and then do some more stuff in that innermost loop with the result (e.g. `if (result === undefined) …`).

Comment: Please use map, filter and reduce array methods instead of for loops. Code will be much readable

Comment: Btw, you probably shouldn't do `firstAddend = list.shift();` but rather `firstAddend = list[i]`. If you want to avoid `i`, `j` and `k` selecting the same element, use `for (let j=i+1; j<…` and `for (let k=j+1; k<…` .

Comment: @captain-yossarian More concise, yes. More readable, not necessarily, especially not for a beginner who is just learning loops. And `map`/`filter`/`reduce` are actually the wrong tools here, you'd need `slice` and `find`.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi. I changed the iterators and got rid of ```l.shift()```, that makes sense. How would ```slice``` and ```find``` be used to solve this problem?

Comment: @captain-yossarian How would ```map``` and ```filter``` work?

Comment: @NicholasBrewer please see the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter I'd willing to bet, once you read these methods, you will refactor your code  :D

Answer (score 2):

> Does each `for` loop contain the scope of the previous?

Yes, it does. Whenever you create a sub-scope, all the variables in the previous scope are available. So, you don't actually have to declare `firstAddend` and `secondAddend` and `thirdAddend` ahead of time:

```js
function testResult(list,sum) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        let firstAddend = list.shift();
        for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            let secondAddend = list[j];
            for (let k = 1; k < list.length; k++) {
                let thirdAddend = list[k];
                addNumbers(firstAddend,secondAddend,thirdAddend,sum);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, the `return` means that when you call the function, it takes on the value that you return. So, you don't need a global `result` variable, as you can just utilize the return value. However, you should move the `if` statement out of the `addNumbers` function and into the `testResult` function, as you need to know when to return, not just what to return. In fact, the `addNumbers` function is simply enough to where it should just go directly into `testResult`:

```js
function testResult(list,sum) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        let firstAddend = list.shift();
        for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            let secondAddend = list[j];
            for (let k = 1; k < list.length; k++) {
                let thirdAddend = list[k];
                if (firstAddend + secondAddend + thirdAddend === sum) {
                    return firstAddend * secondAddend * thirdAddend;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For practice, if you want the function, you could do something like the following:

```js
function addNumbers(first,second,third,sum) {
    if (first + second + third === sum) {
        return (first * second * third);
    } else {
        return null; // return some value so the calling function knows that no sum was found
    }
}

function testResult(list,sum) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        let firstAddend = list.shift();
        for (let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            let secondAddend = list[j];
            for (let k = 1; k < list.length; k++) {
                let thirdAddend = list[k];
                let result = addNumbers(firstAddend, secondAddend, thirdAddend, sum);
                if (result !== null) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That clears things up about scope. Thank you for the detailed answer and explanation!